# How to search for all sheets title starting with Sheet and sum the same cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Users can duplicate a sheet named "**DB**" and the result is something like "**DB (2)**" "**DB (3)**" etc.

In cell `A1` of woksheet "**MAIN**", I want to sum up the `E4` cells from all the duplicated sheets.

Is there a way to loop through all the worksheets and sum up the `E4` cells?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you can loop through all worksheets in the workbook to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Sum of Duplicates

### The Code

```
Sub SumOfDuplicates()

    Const cSheet As String = "MAIN"     ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const cStrSheet As String = "DB ("  ' Compare String
    Const cCellSource As String = "E4"  ' Source Cell Range
    Const cCellTarget As String = "A1"  ' Target Cell Range

    Dim ws As Worksheet   ' Current Source Worksheet
    Dim dblSum As Double  ' Value Accumulator

    ' In This Workbook (i.e. the workbook containing this code)
    With ThisWorkbook
        ' If you also want to add the value from Worksheet "DB" then
        ' uncomment the following line.
        'If IsNumeric(.Worksheets("DB").Range(cCellSource)) Then _
                dblSum = .Worksheets("DB").Range(cCellSource)
        ' Loop through all the worksheets.
        For Each ws In .Worksheets
            ' Check if Current Source Worksheet's name starts with
            ' Compare String.
            If Left(ws.Name, Len(cStrSheet)) = cStrSheet Then
                ' Check if Source Cell Range contains a numeric value.
                If IsNumeric(ws.Range(cCellSource)) Then
                    ' Add value of current Source Cell Range
                    ' to Value Accumulator.
                    dblSum = dblSum + ws.Range(cCellSource)
                End If
            End If
        Next
        ' Write the value of Value Accumulator to Target Cell Range
        ' (in Target Worksheet).
        .Worksheets(cSheet).Range(cCellTarget) = dblSum
    End With

End Sub
```